# How to use temporary table in my model to list with backpack for laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I need to make a report taking information from different tables that are not directly related to each other. I thought that in creating my model that points to a temporary table that I created before, to which I am going to insert the information from the different tables (only some similar specific fields, for example: concept, total).

I would like to know if it is possible? to be able to use the filters and tools provided by the backpack list. And at what point should I create the temporary table so that the model is able to find it?

I did a quick test by adding the code to create the temporary table before the statement:

```
CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Bank::class);
```

In my setup, but it didn't work.

I am saturated and before spending much time on it, I would like to know if this is possible? or if anyone has any suggestions. Thank you very much.

---

UPDATE

I created a function in my model that deletes the temporary table if it exists, creates it with the necessary fields and inserts the records,

```
 $dropTempTables = DB::unprepared(
            DB::raw("
                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bancos ;
            ")
        );

        $createTempTables  = DB::unprepared(DB::raw("
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if not exists bancos (
                id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                nombre VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                id_orden_trabajo BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED  NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                id_orden_compra BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED  NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                fecha_pago DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                total DECIMAL(8,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id) USING BTREE
            );
        "));

        if($createTempTables){
            DB::insert('insert into bancos (nombre, id_orden_trabajo, id_orden_compra, fecha_pago, total) values (?,?, ?, ?, ?)', ['caja', 10, 20, '2022-01-11', 20]);
            DB::insert('insert into bancos (nombre, id_orden_trabajo, id_orden_compra, fecha_pago, total) values (?,?, ?, ?, ?)', ['hola2', 10, 20, '2022-11-11', 20]);
        }
```

I call this function from the "setup" of my controller, then I assign the model which already has that table assigned.

```
CRUD::setModel(\App\Models\Banco::class);
```

The list is displayed correctly, the filters and the pagination, but the search field was not working correctly, so I added 'searchLogic' to the text column and it worked.

```
protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        $this->crud->addColumn([
            'name'        => 'nombre',
            'label'       => 'Nombre',
            'searchLogic' => function ($query, $column, $searchTerm) {
                $query->orWhere('nombre', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            }
        ]);
```

I am only missing the arrows to sort in the header of each column, those noa appear. Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something that brings up these details or could cause problems in future updates?

Comment: Hey Camus, you should also configure the `orderLogic` in the column. Happy to help! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the process:

- You hit the create route, the CrudPanel is created with the `->setModel` you provided.
- The table is ready to draw, it performs an AJAX request to the `/search` endpoint, again, CrudPanel will be created with the model you define.

Probably you need to use the Model boot function to change the table on the run-time in the Model?

Not sure it will work, but it's not a "backpack issue" per-se.

Hope it helps.

Cheers

Comment: Your comments are always helpful.
I updated my post, everything seems to work except for the arrows to sort by column. Could you read it and tell me if you have any comments on it?

cheers